# What happened to flag weight

Tags: support, flagging

Just now I observed that my profile is no longer showing "flag weight" instead it is showing "helpful flags". Where did flag weight go? Is it being replaced with helpful flags count?

Answer (score 8):

The weight of the flag was so awesome that it crushed the pole where it stood. So people all over the community came to give it a "helping hand". many people touched the flag to put it up, that is why the name "helpful flags".

Now the flag floats in the air with magnetized nitrogen ubuntu technology (Which can be viewed only with an Ubuntu TV)..

If you do not believe me read the information I left for you in the directory /dev/null you can find there everything from what happen to the flags, what is the meaning of life, the universe, how to always win the lottery without paying a ticket for it 5 times in a row and how to pick up girls with 10 words or less.

Comment: This needs more upvotes. :)

Answer (score 6):

[It's gone forever, replaced instead with just a count of your helpful flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119715/what-happened-to-flag-weight)

> We now only show the number of helpful flags on your profile page (visible only to you) ... this number only ever increases.
>
> Flag weight on the other hand, is gone ... it is dead.

Comment: If I remember correctly there were few badges related to flagging. Are they gone as well?

Comment: They've been converted to Helpful Flag count.

Comment: @binW have a look at [Anna Lear's](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119717) answer for further introduction to the badges achievements.